# loop puts and appendd

Tags: ruby

I have the following code that reads mac addresses from a file and tries to append test at the end of the mac address.

```
File.open("/RubyDev/sort/mac1.txt",'r').each_line do |a|

    puts "#{a} test"

end
```

This is the output:

```
SEP1C17D3C23929
 test
SEP1C17D3C2B247
 test
SEP1C17D3C24B98
 test
```

I want it to be :

```
SEP1C17D3C23929  test
SEP1C17D3C2B247  test
SEP1C17D3C24B98  test
```

Comment: I took the liberty of formatting the code.  I hope you don't mind.  For next time, you can highlight a block of code and click on the "{}" button.

Comment: The way you're doing it, you're never closing the file. You should use `File.foreach("/RubyDev/sort/mac1.txt") do |a|` instead, which closes the file handle after the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the lines have a new-line ("\n") on the end of them.  To get rid of that, you can call `String#chomp`:

```
puts "#{a.chomp} test"
```

Answer (score 1):

`a` is being returned with a newline character in it.  You need to do: `puts "#{a.strip} test"`

Comment: Or chomp like below if you want to preserve leading and trailing whitespace.